# Custom date picker in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to make a
[custom date picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xln0q.png) like this, how do you think is the best way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

The package `flutter_picker` can help you achieve it:  https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_picker